# Accessing UserControl Resource Dictionary from code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I' am trying to read/load a UserControl Resources from my Home.xaml to a ResourceDictionary object so I can dynamicly display it inside content control and can't manage to find a solution.

I dont want to read it from my App.xaml, just the Home.xaml.
In my View folder I have Home.xaml:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:CheckBoxConverter x:Key="CheckBoxConv"></converters:CheckBoxConverter>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Punomoc">
            <CheckBox Margin="10" Content="Izradi punomoć"
                              IsChecked="{Binding UnosIOS.Punomoc}">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Naknada">
            <CheckBox Margin="10,0" Content="Naplata naknade"
                              IsChecked="{Binding UnosIOS.NaplataNaknade}">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
...
```

```
...

```

In my ConvertersFolder I have:

```
public class CheckBoxConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly ResourceDictionary ControlResourceDictionary;
        static CheckBoxConverter()
        {

            ControlResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
            {
                Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/Home.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
            };

        }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            DataTemplate dataTemplate =ControlResourceDictionary["Punomoc"] as DataTemplate;
            return dataTemplate;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But its returning error:
''The invocation of the constructor on type 'IzdavanjeIOS.Converters.CheckBoxConverter' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '23' and line position '10'.'

Also tried with URI string : MyAppName/View/Home.xaml
I have setup MVVM and dont want to access resources from code-behind unless its the only choice, it seems to me that it should be possible like above, but maybe I am giving the wrong URI?

Comment: The converter should have no knowledge about a potential ResourceDictionary of which it is itself a member. If you want to return different DataTemplates from its Convert method, declare appropriate properties in the CheckBoxConverter class that are assigned by StaticResource expressions in XAML.

Comment: *"I have setup MVVM and dont want to access resources from code-behind"* - Code-behind and MVVM are not mutual exclusive. Code-behind has nothing to do with MVVM. In your case, it looks like you should implement a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/data-template-selector). A IValueConverter is not meant to be used to select the DataTemplate. You didn't provide enough details to help you properly, but what you are doing seems to be just wrong.